# When to use model rewrites in Magento

Tags: category, overrides

I want to know when we should use model rewrites ? What's the down-sides of it ?

I mean when we rewrite a core model class, we should know that no extension can rewrite the core class from now on, so we should rewrite only once or we need to write a local extension to solve rewrite conflicts which is really annoying.

So What's the alternative way ?

i.e In my new module, I want to add a very simple function to Mage_Catalog_Model_Category, so how can I do that without rewriting it ? What do you suggest other than rewriting ? Is rewriting ***Evil*** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's certainly not **evil** - though it does have drawbacks - it is one of those features of Magento that sets it apart and make it a flexible platform. However, like most things, too much of a good thing can quickly become very, very problematic. There are three ways of overriding core functionality:

### Observers

**An observer is always preferable**. Observers don't have this limit of one-per-class. Observers can be slotted *before or after* desired controller actions. You can also tap into model load. They're pretty powerful.

However, they're not a one-size-fits-all solution and it's possible for you to not be able to pinpoint functionality.

### **Rewrites**

Only one rewrite can exist at any time for a given class. Classes attempting to rewrite the same class over and over will have rewrite conflicts. Before you rewrite you want to determine:

- Is this a community module that will be used by *n* stores with *n* plugins installed?
- If so, are there common plugins which rewrite the same class you need to rewrite that perhaps you can code around?
- If not, are you sure that this is insular enough to not cause an issue?

If the above answers can be satisfied, use a rewrite.

### Local Module Overrides

This is never preferable. This is stopgap only if you have a patch for a core issue which has not been issued by Magento yet.

### A word on helpers

You are able to get some code reuse by creating a custom helper. I would avoid helpers that work across modules or in view files - if the helper doesn't exist and your view depends on it then it will throw an exception. I would prefer the rewrite first; however, if this is something that is reusable in potentially dozens of places you would then use a helper. A helper essentially used to keep your code DRY.

---

Which one you use is up to you. The order of precedence is as defined above in my opinion. Best of luck.

Comment: Wow, very great explanation. So many thanks. You clarified it very carefully. Just one question, what do you suggest if I want to add a function to category class ? consider a function to show a magick number related to a specific category. What kind of solutions do you suggest in this situation ?

Comment: That will be a rewrite to add functionality. Great use case for when an observer would not be preferable.

Comment: Great...Thanks for the answer. Isn't a helper do the trick for a small feature like mine I just explained ? I mean create a helper function in my module that anyone can pass category id and then get magick number ? Is it better/safer solution than rewrite?

Comment: I would avoid helpers that work across modules or in view files - if the helper doesn't exist and your view depends on it then it will throw an exception. I would prefer the rewrite first; however, if this is something that is reusable in potentially dozens of places you would then use a helper. A helper essentially used to keep your code DRY

Comment: I set your answer as the accepted one. Just for the last question for future users referring to this: Regarding to our discussion and your great explanation, can we add helpers as the 4th solution to your answer ? If so, can you please add it there, so others like me can see it and compare.

Comment: Greattttt ... You are really awesome. The thing I just afraid of was that maybe having conflicts in a site become an EVIL thing. But after some invesigation and thanks to your great answer I think its not a very big problem and there are many ways to resolve conflicts for the users. So we need to choose the best that fits our needs and if its really the cleanest way, so we should go with it. Conflicts should be handled by the users that using my module and its not a very hard thing to do to resolve the conflicts. Thanksssssss

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting itself is not evil, it's just something you do. Also it's possible to have more than one rewrite per object, it means that you must chain them: Object B extends Object A and Object C extends Object B.

However, you could also check observers (observers are part of Event Driven Architecture). Events are basically hooks that observer is monitoring and once event is dispatched all observers associated with it get executed, no need to chain.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. As I mentioned, I know that they can extends from each other but it then requires more work. For small functionality like the one I wrote as an example what do you suggest ? Can you please let me know what's the alternative for rewrites ? I mean I want to write a module that whoever installs it , he/she can execute a function to show a magick number related to a category. Should we use helpers instead ? Or something else ? So many thanks.